# free-jqgrid: clearGridData problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am having a strange problem using `free-jqgrid 4.9.0`. when I load data into my grid using

```
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: filteredData}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

everything works fine; the data is added to the current grid. 
but i get duplicates this way, so I just wanted to delete the data before adding it:

```
$('#list').jqGrid('clearGridData', true);
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: filteredData}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

this clears the content of my `jqgrid` but fails to add new data.
so as long as I don't use the clearing-part, adding works perfectly. but when i want to add my data to a cleared grid, it doesn't work at all.

thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: try call  `$('#list').jqGrid('clearGridData', true).trigger("reloadGrid")`

Comment: @PauloDiogo i already tried it - did not work either.

Comment: and this: `var g = $("#list");
g.setGridParam({ data: filteredData });
g[0].refreshIndex();
g.trigger("reloadGrid");`? Reference: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/losing-edited-cell-data-after-paging/

Comment: @PauloDiogo will try it tomorrow, when i am back at work.

Comment: @PauloDiogo no, this doesn't work. this gives me a strange javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cb' of undefined`

Comment: I'm in vocation now, so I can't help you much. I can suggest you two alternatives: 1) use the latest options from GitHub which contains fix for clearGridData 2) you can ret **the reference** to internal data by using getGridParam: var p = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam"); p.data= newData; $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");